# PyQt5 Taskbar badge notification

Tags: python, python-3.x, push-notification, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a GUI I am creating with `PyQt5` and the task of this program is to download new information and check that information and compare it to the information the user is searching for. I would like to be able to add a badge with a number to the icon in the taskbar when/if that information is found.

I have been searching google and have not seen any examples of this being done or really any information. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

**Example**

Here is an example from slack for what I am trying to do.

[image: Icon example]

Comment: What do you mean by "badge"? Do you mean a standard (possibly persistent) tray icon or something else (and, in that case, for what operating system)?

Comment: @musicamante the "badge" in my example would be the red circle that covers a small part of the icon in the taskbar that has the number 1 in it. If I have 2 notifications that number turns to 2 and so on. If there are none then it is just the normal program icon. The operating system is windows. They actually have a setting to turn the "badge" on and off.

Comment: Mh, from what I can see, there's no direct support yet (but there is for macOS with the [Qt Mac Extras](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmac.html#setApplicationIconBadgeNumber)).

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56484679/how-to-add-notification-number-to-a-button-icon#56484679

Comment: @S.Nick That is in the program its self. Is there a way to take that answer and change the program's icon this same way, but only update the taskbar icon?

Comment: @S.Nick that is clearly *not* what the OP is asking, please read the question carefully.

Comment: @laxer unfortunately not, as the window icon is the same as it is used on the taskbar.